# How do I stop the execution of an `exec` command from outside the command?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a fastapi route that calls exec on some code. I would like to interrupt the execution of this `exec`'d code from a different API route. How can I do this?

I'm pretty sure this is possible, because I know Jupyter notebooks somehow manage to make this feature work.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about your use case? You can manually stop code execution by clicking stop button in the top or you can use `Stop` from Mercury framework https://runmercury.com/docs/output-widgets/stop/